# Overridding a function in an Inner Class within a test method results in build failure

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xctest

I have the following test method

```
func testSomeClassBehaviour() {
    class TestClass:base{
       //Block starts here------
       override func someFunction() -> [String : String] {
            return Dictionary<String,String>()

        }
        //end---------
    }
    let (result1,Result2) = Utility().processTestObject(testClass())
    XCTAssert("Processed Overridden value","expected value","Some test call")

}
```

With the above method the build failed with error "Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1".

After searching the suggestions in stack overflow, the issue narrowed down to test file and pointed exactly to the block of code within the comments.

Once I comment out the overriden function, its builds and runs, however not with the overridden function.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've found a bug in the swift compiler – you should [file a radar](http://bugreport.apple.com).

This is as minimal a reproduction as I can get:

```
import Foundation

@objc class Outer {
    func method() { }
}

func f() {
    class Inner: Outer {
        override func method() { }
    }
}
```

Has to be an `@objc` class, `Inner` has to override a method in `Outer`, and has to be defined locally within a function.

P.S. you have your capitalization conventions switched around, Swift convention is classes start with capitals, but functions and variables start with lower case.

Comment: Thanks! I will file a bug ticket. Capitalization issues was because of quick find and replace.

Comment: Have raised in radar, Hope its fixed.